# Optional parameters on index route

Tags: php, slim

I have a very simple application where I intend to optionally accept a parameter on the index route such that the user can either go to `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/somethingrandom` I wish to be able to capture the `somethingrandom` as an optional parameter but I am having no luck. Here is my route:

```
$app -> get('/(:random)', function($random=null) use($app) {
    ... do some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So getting this working was not a lack of understanding of the slim framework but to do with my default apache2 setup on OS X. By default in later versions of OS X, PHP is not enabled. This was not **MY** issue but is part of the cause. I followed [this](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083) tutorial to ensure my setup was correct. In addition to this article I had to uncomment the line that loads up the `mod_rewrite` module.

I then created a virtual host in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/tbm/Sites/example.com"
  ServerName shor.ty
  <Directory "/Users/tbm/Sites/example.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and added `127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com` into my hosts file so that I was able to access the site with a domain name from my browser.

Last, thanks to enabling the `mod_rewrite` module, I created a `.htaccess` file that ensured that all requests go through `index.php` allowing the slim router to take over and display the correct page

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Having done all this I was then able to solve my problem using the following syntax

```
$app -> get('/(:random)', function($random=null) use($app) {
  ... do some stuff
});
```

The difference now is that when I visit a page at `/some_string` apache is told to rewrite the request and run `index.php` that then invokes slim to find the correct route and render the correct page. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Slim documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/params/#optional-route-parameters), the `/` needs to be *inside* the parentheses.  So try:

```
$app -> get('(/:random)', function($random=null) use($app) {
    ... do some stuff
});
```

Comment: This does not work. With this in place, I get a 404 when I access my index route. I get a 404

Comment: Does it work if you have something like `/subdir(/:random)`?  This might just be a limitation of Slim :-/

Comment: Ok. Figured it out in the end. `get('/(:random)', ...` works a treat. However this was only half the battle. Turns out I had a few things to configure with the default install of apache2 on OS X. I'll write up the solution as a new answer