# Slim PHP Index Route Optional Parameter

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to set an optional parameter on the index route but can't seem to get it working. I would like to have the option to be able to pass a parameter or not. I can't seem to get anything to work. I was expecting something like the following:

```
$app->get('/(:token)', function ($req, $res){
// Do Something
});
```

I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576322/optional-parameters-on-index-route) which is exactly what I want to achieve but can't seem to get it working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are using the wrong syntax. that is v2... for v3 ... $app->get('/{:token}' ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `token` to be optional, set it in route definition like this:

```
$app->get('/[(:token)]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Will respond to both '/' and '/token'
    // Token value is accessible from $args argument
});
```

Note that the placeholder `{:token}` is wraped in square brackets, which makes it an *optional segment*.

You can read more on the topic in [Slim3 User Guide](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders).

Answer (score 0):

you should use it like this since Version 3  it think

read here: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#get-route

```
   $app->get('/{:token}', function ($req, $res){
      // Do Something
    });
```

Comment: Still no joy with the above, I just get a 404 error.

Comment: Server settings are okay? other sites are working? Or just root? No trailing slash added ?!